# SSRS pagebreak and headers problems

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I've googled and tried the advanced groups settings and tablix properties but still do not get what's desired. I'm using VS2017 with MS SSRS Verson 14.0.1016.268

Added table and pulled in fields from stored procedure I want data from,
    ex: category_id/date/type/name/address/city/state/zip/method/amount/memo

category_id's can be 1-10 and I want it to sort by category_id/date with each new category_id causing a pagebreak with the header row repeated on each page. If it looks like it's doing the appropriate page breaks it does not repeat the header rows; though often in my trials and errors I get one record per page. Much thanks to anyone who can make this clearer.

Comment: Can you show what you have done already, what properties have you set and to what values in your tablix. Also if you can edit your question to show a screen shot of the report design that will help you get an answer more quickly,

Answer (score 0):

I would put your table in another **List**. The List makes it easier to control page breaks and tab names (in Excel).

Create a List (which is a table with one column).

Remove the Header.

Use the same dataset as your table.

Group the List By the CAT ID.

Use the Advanced properties to set the CAT group with a Page Break **Between** Groups.

Put your current table in the data section of the list.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the feedback. New and fumbling through. I had training four years ago but not thrown into doing til now. Can you put multiple tables in a list? Because I discovered except for first three categories others have different fields to be shown. So I got each category listing on its on new page by putting a separate table in a rectangle for each but I think by doing that I won't be able to have the repeating footer showing page number out of how many pages and that's a desired aspect of the report.

Answer (score 0):

What worked to make a new page with headers repeated when the category changed was to put my table in a rectangles.

So I've got 10 table-containing rectangles one for each category and when category id# in the table changes it causes a pagebreak.

Comment: Though this now causes a new problem whereas it's desirable to have "page #/out of # pages" on the bottom of each page I'm not sure if I can achieve this with the separate rectangles...